# How to check if object is undefined/null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

This question has come up a lot but I can't make it work.

I have 5 divs, I want to hide the div before the last one who was used. So If the user clicks somewhere in div 1, and then clicks somewhere in div 2, div 1 fades out (all of this after an Ajax call)

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#[id^='r_form_']").bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
        var $form = $(this);

        $(this).parent().css("background", "green");

        if($lastForm == null) {
            var $lastForm = $(this);
        };

        if(!($lastForm[0] == $form[0])) {
            $lastForm.parent().fadeOut(1500);
            var $lastForm = $(this);
        };
    });
});
```

If the variable `$lastForm` is undefined, assign the current form where Ajax happenned.

The variable is always undefined. I added an `alert('undefined')` in the loop, i always get it. why?

I have a feeling it might be because the variable is reset when the Ajax request comes back. But i'm not really an expert and can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Code tips: There's no reason to put a `;` after a block (i.e. after all the `if`s here), and you can use `a != b` instead of `!(a == b)`.

Comment: Also, there should not be a `#` at the beginning of your selector, take it out.

Comment: Tip: in this case it's shorter/easier to write `if (!$lastForm)`.

Comment: @minitech. but it's being called, so... go figure.

Comment: @Phrogz. you're right, but should be noted that if `$lastForm` can being `0` it was treated like it was false. But you're right in this case(and you mentioned that! just clarified your wise comment...)

Comment: @gdoron: jQuery is pretty lenient when it comes to that, but it will make the whole thing much less efficient - `document.querySelectorAll` won't accept that kind of string, and so jQuery will have to parse, compile and execute it itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because it's declared in inner scope. move the declaration to outside of the function. each function create a new scope, so it's not saved to the next call:

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $lastForm; //<===================
    $("#[id^='r_form_']").bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
        var $form = $(this);

        $(this).parent().css("background", "green");

        if ($lastForm == null) {
            $lastForm = $(this);
        };

        if (!($lastForm[0] == $form[0])) {
            $lastForm.parent().fadeOut(1500);
            $lastForm = $(this);
        };
    });
});​
```

As commented by @minitech the `#` in the selector: `#[id^='r_form_']` looks like it shouldn't be there.

Comment: You might want to change the second `var $lastForm`, too - otherwise the whole thing breaks.

Comment: Brilliant. Fantastic. Thanks a lot. Concerning the #, I have several Ajax actions associated. So its not really `$("#[id^='r_form_']").bind("ajax:success",` but `.bind("ajax...``. If I take the # away, it gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof e === 'undefined') {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: You have a typo with the string, and anyway, I'm sorry but I don't understand how does it solve the problem? `null == undefined`! [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tT8X/)

Comment: People should really think twice before they upvote, If you don't know if it is right or wrong, don't vote...

Comment: (You should probably delete this answer now.)